# Sending TestNG Report to Stout instead of file

Tags: testng

In TestNG is it possible to send the contents of testng-report.xml to stdout instead of to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. Why do you need this?

Comment: Because I wrote a CGI that takes a url as a parameter and returns the the contents of testng-results.xml. The only way for me to do that now is to let TestNG write the reports to a temp directory, read the file, print the contents, and delete the tmp directory. I'd rather be able to hook into the results and print it out directly. I know I can create my own custom report and do what I want with it, but why when there's already very complete reports...